# invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘color’)

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following source code, which allocates space for an image, its pixels and read the pixel values.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>



typedef struct color
{
    int r,g,b;
}color;


typedef struct image
{
    int width, height;
    color *pixels;
}image;

image* CreateImage(int width, int height)
{

    imagem *im=NULL;
    im=(image*)malloc(sizeof(image));
    im->height=height;
    im->width=width;
    im->pixels=(color*)malloc(width*height*sizeof(color));

    int i;

    //error starts here
    for (i=0; i<width*height;i++)
    {
        scanf('%d', &im->pixels[i]->r);
        scanf('%d', &im->pixels[i]->g);
        scanf('%d', &im->pixels[i]->b);

    }


return im;
}
```

The problem starts in the part of the code where the image pixels are read. When I compile it, the error is 'invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘color’)'

I know that we must use '->' if the left operand is a pointer. Here image and pixels are pointers, so why can't I use im->pixels[i]->r, for example? how can I solve this problem?

Comment: `im->pixels[i]` is not a pointer. Change `im->pixels[i]->` to `im->pixels[i].`.

Comment: I'm also uncertain of how tightly that `&` is binding, I'd put parenthesis around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", &im->pixels[i].r);

pixels[i] = *(pixels + i); /* [] has already dereferenced */
```

As shown above you need to have double quotes in your scanf() instead of single quote

Comment: Now I have segmentation fault

Comment: Where is the segmentation fault?  What are `i`, `height`, and `height` during the segmentation fault?

Answer (score 5):

`pixels` is indeed a pointer, but your use of the `[]` has already dereferenced it.  You want:

```
 &im->pixels[i].r
```

Note that your `scanf` call should have a string as a first parameter, not a multicharacter literal - use double quotes there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `->` operator if you really want:

```
( im->pixels+i )->r = 123 ;
```

This is identical to

```
im->pixels[i].r = 123 ;
```